# How to display only one data at a time in an online quiz

Tags: php, isset

I've previously made a text file and turned it into multidimensional array to display as the questions for my quiz.

***Note:** I am unable to insert images therefore I cannot provide any example so I'll try to be as descriptive as I can.*

I'm trying to display only one question at a time, every time a user clicks on my quiz.

This is my code so far. The **main.php** page:

```
<h2>ONLINE QUIZ</h2>
<ul>
    <li><a href='question.php'>Take quiz</a></li>
    <li><a href='module.php'>Admin Module</a></li>
</ul>
<?php

$file = fopen('data.txt', 'r');

$array = array();
while ($line = fgetcsv($file)) {
    $array[] = $line;
}

fclose($file);

session_start();
$_SESSION["questions_array"]=$array;

?>
```

And the **question.php** page:

```
<?php

session_start();
$array=$_SESSION["questions_array"];

foreach ($array as $q => $data) {
    echo '<p>'.array_shift($data).'</p>';
    foreach ($data as $a => $answer) {
        echo 
             '  <input type="radio" name="question-'.$q.'" id="question-'.$q.'"'.
             '         value="'.$a.'"/>'.
             '  <label for="question-'.$q.'">'.$answer.'</label>'.
             '<br>';
    }

}

?>
```

When the `Take quiz` link is clicked, the user is taken to the question page where only one question is shown. The user then picks an answer and hits `submit`. This submit button will take the user to the result page where they can then hit `continue`.

The `Continue` link will redirect them back to the question page where the next question is displayed.

From stuff that I've done before, I am attempting to use the `isset()` function to make this happen. However, the problem is that I'm not sure how exactly to write my `isset()`.

I've found this snippet from this site, I'm not sure if it's useful, but:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['FirstVisit'])) {

    //show site for the first time part
    $_SESSION['FirstVisit] = 1;
    header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");

    // Don't forget to add http colon slash slash www dot before!

    } else { Show normal site }
```

But once again I found myself blank. How exactly do I use the `isset()` to display only one question?

Comment: Can you give us a var_dump of your $_SESSION array?

Comment: ($q, $a, $answer, $data)

Comment: That's not what I asked for.. do var_dump($_SESSION["questions_array"]); on your questions page and post the results here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kinda get what your asking, Ive jotted out the basic structure. This can all be done on one page, hope it helps.

EDIT:

As im such a nice guy heres a complete script, using my prev suggestion ;p

```
<?php
session_start();
echo '<h2>ONLINE QUIZ</h2>';


//Scores
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset($_GET['scores'])){
    echo 'Basic output for scores';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_SESSION['answers']);
    echo '</pre>';
    unset($_SESSION['answers']);
    unset($_SESSION['question']);
}


//Session question/array is set
if(isset($_SESSION['question']) && isset($_SESSION['questions_array'])){

    //Handle prev question post
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        //process prev question
        $_SESSION['answers'][$_SESSION['question']-1]=(0+$_POST['answer']);
    }

    if($_SESSION['question'] < $_SESSION['total_question']){
        $q=$_SESSION['question'];
        //EDIT - Shuffle answers for output
        //Hold the question into a var
        $question = $_SESSION['questions_array'][$q][0];
        //unset the question from the array
        unset($_SESSION['questions_array'][$q][0]);
        //put all the pos answers into a new array
        $answers = $_SESSION['questions_array'][$q];
        //shuffle the answers
        shuffle($answers);


        echo '<form method="POST" action="">
              <h3>'.$question.'</h3>';
        //loop through the answers
        foreach($answers as $key=>$value){
            //if the value is nothing cont to next, removed question key 0
            if($value==''){continue;}else{
                echo '<p><input type="radio" value="'.$value.'" name="answer">'.$value.'</p>';
            }
        }
        echo '<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </form>';

    }else{
        //Quiz Complete
        echo 'Test Complete <a href="'.basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]).'?scores=1">Check scores</a>';
    }

    //Assign next question to session
    $_SESSION['question']++;
}else{

    //Pages first load so show quiz index
    $_SESSION['question']=0;
    get_questions();
?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='<?=basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);?>'>Take quiz</a></li>
        <li><a href='module.php'>Admin Module</a></li>
    </ul>
    <?php
}

//Function to put questions in session
function get_questions(){
    $file = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
    $array = array();
    while ($line = fgetcsv($file,1000,',')) {
        $array[] = $line;
    }
    fclose($file);
    $_SESSION['questions_array']=$array;
    $_SESSION['total_question']=count($array);
    return;
}
?>
```

Comment: It will post to it self thats the idea, note: `<?=basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);?>`

Comment: Hey, so I tried this and received no errors, however it just displays a blank page. I'm now trying to find what may have caused this. Would you happen to have any idea?

Comment: perhaps `$_SESSION['question']` is greater then the amount of questions left and is hitting the Quiz Complete
part that has no output, its only a basic basic structure you still have to build appon it.

Comment: Yea, I like this solution. It's clean. Much more robust. +1

Comment: @user1344705 Ive updated my answer to a working version, reason it was blank was because of the missing delimiter on the fgetcsv function

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you so much for your time! I need the submit button to lead me to a temporary result page where the user needs to click a 'continue' link to see the next question but this is very, very helpful! +1

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Hello, sorry to bother again but I'm just wondering if there is any possible way to shuffle/sort the 'answers' without affecting their index values in this code?

Comment: yeah just before you set the seesion within the get_questions function do `fclose($file); shuffle($array);`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tried that but it shuffles the questions plus the answers. I only want the answers (radio buttons) sorted so that the correct answer isn't always at the top (as I've set it that way). Would you happen to have any idea on how I can do that?

Comment: ok ive updated my answer to include a possible answer shuffle (to much to explain) as things get more complex it may just be easyier to make a database to hold stuff... hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the solution to your problem to do another array shift on the outter array. By this you can pull off one question and print it out. The quiz is preserved in the session, so the next time the page loads (i.e. the continue button is clicked) it pulls off the next question.

Questions Page:

```
<?php

session_start();
if(sizeof($_SESSION['questions_array']) > 0 )
{
    // Get the next question off of the Quiz in our SESSION
    $data = array_shift($_SESSION["questions_array"]);

    echo '<p>'.array_shift($data).'</p>'; // pop the question

    //list out the possible answers
    foreach ($data as $a => $answer) 
    {
        echo 
               '  <input type="radio" name="question-'.$q.'" id="question-'.$q.'"'.
               '         value="'.$a.'"/>'.
               '  <label for="question-'.$q.'">'.$answer.'</label>'.
               '<br>';

    }

}
else
{
  //questions array is empty, show quiz complete page
}

?>
```

Now your questions page only brings back one question. When submit is clicked they go to the answers page. When continue is clicked they come back. Our system then does as follows:
1) Are there questions left in our array?
  A)Yes
    A.1) Okay pop the next question with array_shift($_SESSION['questions_array'])
    A.2) Pop the question then list the answers.
  B)No
    B.1) No more questions, our quiz is over.

Note: There are some draw backs. If the person refreshes the page they get a new question and the other one goes unanswered. You could alternatively pass a $counter variable that updates each time the answer page loads. Then pass that counter to the $_SESSION array to bring back the next question. It's up to you.

Comment: Yea.. that "flow chart" looked a lot better when it wasn't pushed together.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Would this code require a new page or may I add this to my question page? --I tried to add it to my question page and the page still displayed all the questions :(

Comment: Did you replace what you had? I'm saying use this instead of what you have listed in your question. No new page is needed. Put this on your questions page instead of what you had.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much =] I'll keep the draw backs in mind as well!