# Laravel Query issue

Tags: laravel

I have make the survey site. User post the question and other user ans them the question.My code work perfectly but the views is not good. All the question shows the user.How we can one by one show the question. User press the next button then show the next question if press the previous button show the previous question.
Any Idea for this problem Or suggest me related site

Comment: Please can you add the code you're having issue with?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers or https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with Javascript or similar.

But, I too did find this way interesting as well using php only and please check whether they could help. 
[How to display only one data at a time in an online quiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236123/how-to-display-only-one-data-at-a-time-in-an-online-quiz)
OR
[One quiz item per page (php/mysql quiz program)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136151/one-quiz-item-per-page-php-mysql-quiz-program)